# A question about the differentiability of two Weyl sums

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, summation

Consider the following functions, associated with certain trigonometrical sums:
$$ f_{\alpha,\beta}(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(n^{\alpha+\beta}x)}{n^{\alpha}},\qquad g_{\alpha,\beta}(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(n^{\alpha+\beta}x)}{n^{\alpha}}.$$
For $\alpha>1$, they clearly belong to $C^{0}(\mathbb{R})$ since they are total converging series of continuous functions. My questions now are:

- Is is true that $f_{\alpha,\beta}$ and $g_{\alpha,\beta}$ are nowhere-differentiable for any $\alpha>1,\beta\geq 0$?
- For which values of $\alpha,\beta$ is $f_{\alpha,\beta}$ continuous and nowhere-differentiable?
- For which values of $\alpha,\beta$ is $g_{\alpha,\beta}$ continuous and nowhere-differentiable?

Comment: I'd be a bit surprised if the last two points had distinct answers, since that's equivalent to having the real and imaginary parts of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-\alpha} \exp(i n^{\alpha+\beta} x)$ have different smoothness properties.

Comment: @Semiclassical: I do not believe they differ, too, but since $\forall k\in\mathbb{Z}, \sin(k\pi)=0$ it *may* happen that $f_{\alpha,\beta}$ is differentiable in every point of $\pi\mathbb{Z}$ while $g_{\alpha,\beta}$ is nowhere-differentiable.